# Problem Initializing an Array Of Structs

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to initialize the following array of the following struct, but my code isn't compiling. Can anybody help me out?

The struct/array:

```
struct DiningCarSeat {
    int status;
    int order;
    int waiterNum;
    Lock customerLock;
    Condition customer;

    DiningCarSeat(int seatNum) {
        char* tempLockName;
        sprintf(tempLockName, "diningCarSeatLock%d", seatNum);
        char* tempConditionName;
        sprintf(tempConditionName, "diningCarSeatCondition%d", seatNum);
        status = 0;
        order = 0;
        waiterNum = -1;
        customerLock = new Lock(tempLockName);
        customer = new Condition(tempConditionName);
    }
} diningCarSeat[DINING_CAR_CAPACITY];
```

The relevant errors:

```
../threads/threadtest.cc: In constructor `DiningCarSeat::DiningCarSeat(int)':
../threads/threadtest.cc:58: error: no matching function for call to `Lock::Lock()'
../threads/synch.h:66: note: candidates are: Lock::Lock(const Lock&)
../threads/synch.h:68: note:                 Lock::Lock(char*)
../threads/threadtest.cc:58: error: no matching function for call to `Condition::Condition()'
../threads/synch.h:119: note: candidates are: Condition::Condition(const Condition&)
../threads/synch.h:121: note:                 Condition::Condition(char*)
../threads/threadtest.cc:63: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
../threads/threadtest.cc:64: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
../threads/threadtest.cc: At global scope:
../threads/threadtest.cc:69: error: no matching function for call to `DiningCarSeat::DiningCarSeat()'
../threads/threadtest.cc:51: note: candidates are: DiningCarSeat::DiningCarSeat(const DiningCarSeat&)
../threads/threadtest.cc:58: note:                 DiningCarSeat::DiningCarSeat(int)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues here:

These should both be pointers, since you are `new`ing them in your constructor:

```
Lock customerLock;
Condition customer;
```

You don't declare a type for `seatNum`:

```
DiningCarSeat(seatNum) {
```

You don't allocate memory for `tempLockName` or `tempConditionName`:

```
    char* tempLockName;
    sprintf(tempLockName, "diningCarSeatLock%d", seatNum);
    char* tempConditionName;
    sprintf(tempConditionName, "diningCarSeatCondition%d", seatNum);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

I've got more questions though...

I don't think I want pointers for customerLock and customer...how should I be initializing them instead?

Ah, I'm still not used to having to do stuff like allocating memory and would never have caught that on my own. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Condition` and `Lock` are have no default constructors. You should use [initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) to construct them.

I would change/add constructors for `Condition` and `Lock` so they could accept `const char*` and `int`. Then `DiningCarSeat` will look like:

```
DiningCarSeat(int seatNum) : 
  status(0), 
  order(0), 
  waiterNum(-1), 
  cutomerLock( "diningCarSeatLock", seatNum), 
  customer("diningCarSeatCondition", seatNum) 
{}
```

Comment: So does that mean classes need default constructors no matter what? I thought I wouldn't need them because I wasn't using them...

What's an initialization list?

Comment: You could read [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html) about initialization lists.